# Changing the transaction management class timeout does not impact the SqlTransaction and TransactionScope class

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am setting the time out using reflection which is overriding the machine.config transaction time(as we can not override the transaction timeout using config file).let say current time out is 5 second.

Now I in the SqlTransaction scope, I am putting the app for sleep in 10 second but still it wont throw timeout exception.Same is with TransactionScope class.

Please help explaining the relationship between SqlTransaction/TransactionScope and TransactionManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        try
        {
            Type transType = typeof (System.Transactions.TransactionManager);
            FieldInfo cachedMaxTimeOut = transType.GetField("_cachedMaxTimeout", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            FieldInfo maximumTimeOut = transType.GetField("_maximumTimeout", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

            if (null != cachedMaxTimeOut)
            {
                cachedMaxTimeOut.SetValue(null, true);
            }
            if (null != maximumTimeOut)
            {
                maximumTimeOut.SetValue(null, timeout);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Exception handling or logging.
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding, why not set it in the code:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions() { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,5) }))
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: This is useful but of you have the timeout setup in machine.config, that will get the precedence.I resolved with the help of reflection and overwriting the timeout.

Comment: Yes, machine.config will get precedence.  I guess why are you relying on machine.config since this seems to need application-level support?

Comment: When the application will go on client machine, we can not simply assume that everything will be fine(machine.config).Secondly it has default timeout of 10 min but there are migration task which takes hour an hour to finish that is the reason I wanted to go with that approach.